# SpriteKit having trouble removing nodes from scene

Tags: sprite-kit

I have a method that creates a object that moves across the screen, and i run this method a lot of times to produce a lot of objects, but what i can't do now is remove them when i need to. I've tried

```
childNodeWithName("monster")?.removeFromParent()
```

but that doesn't work, they still complete their action. This is the method

```
func spawn() {

    let ran = Int(arc4random_uniform(1400));
    var  monster = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "spike")
    monster = SKSpriteNode(texture: text)
    monster.position = CGPoint(x: ran, y: 800);
    monster.zPosition = 1;
    monster.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: text, size: text.size())
    monster.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Monster
    monster.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Player
    monster.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    monster.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    monster.name = "monster"
    self.addChild(monster);

    let move = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(monster.position.x, -100), duration: 1.5);
    let remove = SKAction.runBlock { () -> Void in
        monster.removeFromParent()
        self.score += 1
    }
    monster.runAction(SKAction.sequence([move,remove]))
}
```

How can i remove every "monster" node at once when i need to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove every monster node at once you can use SKNode's [enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock:) method, like this:

```
self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("monster") {
                        node, stop in

                        node.removeAllActions()
                        node.removeFromParent()                       
 }
```

Here, self is a scene because you've added monsters to the scene. If you for example added monsters to some container node, then you should run this method on that node, eg. `containerNode.enumerateChildNodesWithName("monster"){...}`